# How can i send a json object to .net server using signalr

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, signalr

I am developing an Angular app, where i have to send data from angular forms to an external server using .netcore server and signalR. I am able to setup a connection between Angular client and controller using signalr hub but i am confused how to send json object from client to controller. From controller i want to send the Json object to external server. I want to implement this using signalr because i want realtime communication between external server and client. when i submit the data and recieve response from external server i want to alert client.I am looking for some guidance on how can i implement this.

Angular client

```
_hubConnection: HubConnection;
 transportType = signalR.HttpTransportType.LongPolling;

ngOnInit() {
   this._hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .withUrl("http://localhost:5000/message", this.transportType)
    .build();
}

fun1(){
 this._hubConnection.on("Send", (user, message) => {
  const received = `name: ${user}, message: ${message}`;
  console.log(received);
});

this._hubConnection.start()
    .then(() =>
        this._hubConnection.invoke('Send', "rk", "wassup").catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err.toString());
    })
)
.then(() =>
    console.log('connected')
)
.then(() => this._hubConnection.stop())
.then(() => console.log('Disconnected'))
.catch(e => console.error(e.message));
```

Controller

```
namespace ang.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DistController : Controller
    {
        private IHubContext<DistHub> _hubContext;
        public DistController(IHubContext<DistHub> hubContext)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }
    }
}
```

SignalRhub

```
namespace ang.HubConfig
{
    public class DistHub: Hub
    {
        public async Task Send (string user , string message)
        {
            // return Clients.All.SendAsync("Send", message);
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("Send", user, message);
        }
    }
}
```

startup.cs

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
    routes.MapHub<DistHub>("/message");
});
```

json object

```
const Root = {
  "Unit" : "mm",
  "test": [{
    "Val": this.Val1.isChecked,
    'Val1' : this.val2.isChecked,
  }],
  "test1" :{
    "sub":[{
      'val2' : this.valFormGroup.get('val2').value,
      'Val3' : this.valFormGroup.get('val3').value,
    }]
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this by passing in the root data to the invoke

```
connection.invoke('Send', "rk", "wassup", Root);
```

Then in your hub add another params for the root data

```
public async Task Send (string user , string message, string root)
{
  await Clients.All.SendAsync("Send", user, message);
}
```

Update since you are submit json string you can use

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(root);
```

Comment: Hi @Tony Ngo, Thanks for your time. I have tried the above solution. How can i read the values from the "Root" object from Angular. I have created a model for the Root object in c# and it contains a class "root". Is it possible to display the data to console to verify if the data is correct.

Comment: You can run debug mode in visual studio

Comment: ok. I will check it. can you please explain what is "root" object. is it the Josn object "Root" or "root" class from the Root Model.

Comment: Seem like your json is not having the strong type so I think you can use `object` data in c#. You can check it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types

Answer (score 1):

If the json data that you want to send from client is in known and fixed format, you can make your Hub method accept custom object parameter, like below.

Hub method

```
public async Task GetCustomData(string user, Root data)
{

    var sub_val2 = data.test1.sub[0].val2.ToString();

    //code logic here


    await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, "{message_here}");
}
```

Custom Classes

```
public class Root
{
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public List<Test> test { get; set; }
    public Test1 test1 { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public bool Val { get; set; }
    public bool Val1 { get; set; }
}

public class Test1
{
    public List<Sub> sub { get; set; }
}

public class Sub
{
    public string val2 { get; set; }
    public string Val3 { get; set; }
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Besides, as Tony Ngo shared, modify Hub method to make it accept another object type parameter is also ok.