# Send a json object to .net server using signalr and Java client

Tags: java, c#, asp.net-core-signalr

I am using SignalR 5.0, I am trying to send a JSON from the Android client. I have looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58093494/how-can-i-send-a-json-object-to-net-server-using-signalr). But it's not working for me, the send works I get  the json in the test "{"Id":"123123","ReceviedDateTime":"Nov 23, 2020 12:50:55 PM","RepliedDatetime":"Nov 23, 2020 12:50:55 PM"}" but the Pong method is never called. Added
services.AddSignalR().AddJsonProtocol(); in the startup

Pong model:

```
public class PongModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime SendDatetime { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReceviedDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime RepliedDatetime { get; set; }
}
```

Java code:
[image]

Methods (.net core 5)

```
    public void Pong(PongModel pongModel)
    {
    }

    public void Send(string test)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Your server logs should clarify the issue. Likely mapping to the model is not correct. For example - in your json Id is string, but in model class it's int. Dates format might also be problematic

Comment: Yes, it works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass object directly example without serializing: hubConnection.send("Pong", p);
Add  this to get the binding error:
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR": "Debug",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections": "Debug"